# fixing width of a gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, width, fixed

I want to fix width of gridview. I am filling gridview as following;

```
sorgu = "select urun.urunId as \"İş No\",urun.modelNo as \"Model No\",modelAd as \"Model Adı\",bedenAd as \"Beden\", adet as \"Adet\""
              + ",aciklama as \"Açıklama\", kesmeTalimat as \"Kesim Talimatı\", atolyeTalimat as \"Atölye Talimatı\", yikamaTalimat as \"Yıkama Talimatı\", utuTalimat as \"Ütü Talimatı\", (k4.ad+' '+k4.soyad) as \"Kesim\", (k1.ad+' '+k1.soyad) as \"Atölye\""
              + ",(k2.ad+' '+k2.soyad) as \"Yıkama\",(k3.ad+' '+k3.soyad) as \"Ütü\", (k5.ad+' '+k5.soyad) as \"Kontrol\" from kullanici k1,kullanici k4,kullanici k5,kullanici k2,kullanici k3,model,beden,urun,fason,isTalimat,durum"
              + " where urun.urunId= fason.urunId and urun.urunId=isTalimat.urunId and urun.urunId=durum.urunId and model.modelNo=urun.modelNo and beden.bedenNo=urun.bedenNo and"
              + " fason.atolye=k1.id and fason.yikama=k2.id and fason.kesimci=k4.id and fason.kontrol=k5.id and fason.utu=k3.id";
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = sorgu;
        dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dtTumISler = new DataTable();
        dtTumISler.Load(dr);
        dgvTumIsler.DataSource = dtTumISler;
        dgvTumIsler.DataBind();
        dr.Close();
        connection.Close();
        dtTumISler.Dispose();
```

Here dgvTumİsler is my gridview. I have tried the following code to make fixed length. But it does not work;

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvTumIsler.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dgvTumIsler.Columns[i].ItemStyle.Width = 100;
        }
```

Here dgvTumİsler.Columns.Count  value is 1. So it does not work. Is there a way to solve this problem or is there another way to make a gridview fixed width.

HTML code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvTumIsler" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgvTumIsler_SelectedIndexChanged">
                         <Columns>
                             <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" SelectText="Seç" ShowCancelButton="False" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                         </Columns>
                         <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" />
                         <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                         <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                   </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you please add your GridView HTML code also?

Comment: I have added HTML code

Comment: Do you have only 1 column in grid? if yes then please also set the width of grid to 100px

Comment: no, I have many columns more than ten

Comment: But I can see only 1 column in grid view in Gridview HTML.

Comment: I use sql query to fill gridview

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can do it.Give it a try

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" width="600px">

    <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserId" 
                    DataField="UserId" 
                    SortExpression="UserId" ItemStyle-Width="400px"></asp:BoundField>
       </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: did you add width to your gridview? Use firebug.Track down the if any css is being applied to your gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) attribute to set a css class and use that to set the width

```
<RowStyle CssClass="myRow">
...
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" SelectText="Seç" CssClass="mybutton"/>
...
<style>
.myRow td{width: 100px;}
.mybutton{width: 100px}
</style>
```

Comment: I want to make all columns fixed width

Comment: Then add the same css class to all columns.

Comment: the columns are generated with sql query not static

Comment: Just apply CssClass to the row style and set the cell width using a CSS child selector. Like `.myRow td{width: 100px}`